# When comparing action of a spring, with and without mass, on another mass, how accurate is it to state that the work done is the same in both cases?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Consider a spring of mass $M$, length $L_0$, and spring force constant $k$, fixed on one end and free on the other.

Assume the mass is distributed evenly through the length of the spring.

Consider a scenario in which the free end of the spring is moving with speed $v$, and make the assumption that the speed of each point along the spring is a linear function of the distance to the fixed end of the spring.

$$v(l)=al \implies v(L_0)=aL_0=v\implies a=v/L_0$$

$$v(l)=\frac{vl}{L_0}$$

If we consider a very small piece of the spring, of length $dl$ we have

$$dm=\frac{dl}{L_0}M$$

The kinetic energy of the whole spring is

$$\int \frac{1}{2}v_{dl}^{2}dm=\int \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{vl}{L_0}\right)^2 \left( \frac{dl}{L_0}M \right)=\frac{v^2 M}{2L_0^3} \int_{0}^{L_0} l^2dl=\frac{Mv^2}{6}$$

Note that the kinetic energy of the spring is lower than $\frac{1}{2}Mv^2$.

Consider a scenario in which the spring is now compressed a certain amount $x_0$, and a ball of mass $m$ is attached to it. What is the speed of the ball when the spring passes through its equilibrium position (ie the position at which the spring force is zero)?

If we disregard the mass of the spring, we just calculate the work done by the spring force on the ball and equate this with the change in the ball's kinetic energy.

$$W=\int_{-x_0}^{0} -kx dx=\frac{kx_0^2}{2}$$
$$W=\Delta K \implies \frac{kx_0^2}{2}=\frac{1}{2}mv^2\implies v=\frac{\sqrt{mk}x_0}{m}$$

If we now consider the mass of the spring, we have that the total work done is still the same, but now we consider the kinetic energy of the spring as it passes position zero with some speed v, which as we calculated previously as $\frac{Mv^2}{4L_0}$.

$$W=\frac{kx_0^2}{2}=\frac{Mv^2}{6}+\frac{1}{2}mv^2=\Delta K$$
$$\implies v=\frac{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{(M+3m)k}x_0}{M+3m}$$

My question is in regard to one simple step in this calculation: the part where I said the when we consider the mass of the spring the work done is still the same. The spring force is performing work; we basically consider that the work is done at the contact point between spring and ball; that is the point that undergoes the displacement that we use to calculate work. But each small piece of the spring undergoes a different displacement. Is it actually accurate to state that the work done when we consider the mass of the spring is the same as when we disregard it?

Comment: What makes you think that the velocity will vary linearly with material distance alone the spring?

Comment: @ChetMiller - it is an assumption, a reasonable one for a near quasi-static situation.  A line is a close approximation to a sine wave for small arguments numerically.

Comment: The linear relationship of speed with distance along the spring is simply an assumption.

Answer (score 2):

The work done by a spring between a deflection $x_1$ and a deflection $x_2$ is the same, regardless of all of the other aspects of the system.  This is because the potential energy stored by the spring at a deflection $x$ is $\frac1 2 kx^2$, and that energy is conserved.

Now, this assumes an ideal spring and a traditional definition of 'work,' which permits things like self-work.  Some of that work is being applied to the spring.  Whether this is the correct equation to use in your particular situation is a matter of context.  If you are modeling a system where the mass is a bowling ball that is going to be flung far away by the force of the spring, you may explicitly wish to exclude this self-work, as it isn't "useful work." Often enough we will skip much of the rigor you went through, and treat such a system as non-conservative -- we apply work to the ball and dissipate the energy put into the velocity of the spring as heat.  On the other hand, if your system remains connected, such as the springs in a shock absorber system on a car, all of that energy put into the movement of the mass-ful spring will be returned to spring energy as it bounces back.

But, based on your equations, and the way you're thinking about the problem, it is correct to say that energy is conserved, and the amount of work done is the same in both cases.  It's merely a question of how that work is distributed between elements of the system.

Comment: This is only true if the stretch in the spring is uniform over its length.  The stretch is uniform if the spring is at rest, but it is not uniform for a massive spring in motion.  Solving the equations of motion for a massive spring show that the velocity varies widely over the length of the spring if the mass of the spring is comparable to a mass on the end.  It is especially true for a lone spring with no mass on the end.

Comment: @BillWatts I'm not sure which part of the answer you are referring to.  Are you thinking of the case where the spring may have the same deflection but different internal energy because of transient behaviors?  I sought to hold as close to "energy is conserved" as I could in the answer, but did I miss a detail where I assumed too much?

Comment: I was merely trying to point out that if the stretch in the spring is not constant over its length, then $\frac{k x^2}{2}$ will not strictly be the energy, because the spring tension is not constant. With no damping, the energy is indeed constant, but I believe a better calculation for it is $\int F \, dx$.  A knowledge of how the tension varies with length would naturally be required.  If the spring always starts out from rest, then the initial and subsequent energy would be $\frac{k x^2}{2}$ with $x$ the initial stretch.

Comment: @BillWatts Ahh, that makes sense.  That does seem like the natural progression from ideal springs, to springs with masses, to non-linear springs.